# SoftAssert shows error messages twice

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I'm running tests with Intellij IDEA using TestNG as a testing framework. If some soft asserts are failing, then I get duplicated error messages. Here's my test method:

```
@Test
public void canNotContinueWithoutMandatoryInfo() {
   applicant.continueExpectingErrors();
   SoftAssert sf = new SoftAssert();
   for (String label : fields) {
     sf.assertEquals(applicant.getFieldRequiredNotification(label), fieldIsMandatoryError, "Notification for " +
      label + " is either invalid or missing\n");
   }
   sf.assertAll();
}
```

And at the output I am getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    Notification for field Account is either invalid or missing
    Notification for field Account is either invalid or missing
 expected [This field is mandatory.] but found [null], 
    Notification for field Name is either invalid or missing
    Notification for field Name väli is either invalid or missing

Expected :This field is mandatory.
Actual   :null
      <Click to see difference>
```

What am I doing wrong?

You can reproduce this by running a simple test like this:

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    SoftAssert sf = new SoftAssert();
    Integer[] list = {1, 2, 3};
    for(int i : list)
      sf.assertEquals(3, i, i + " does not equal 3\n");
    sf.assertAll();
  }
```

Comment: post more code..what code is filling in fields list/arr?

Comment: added a simple example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug in TestNG. Has nothing to do with the for loop, messages are duplicated always.